# What does "cache write" mean?

Tags: algorithm, caching

The task is to count "cache writes" during some algorithm work.
So what's cache write? 
Is it a process when data is written to the cache or what?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in your lecture notes or textbook.

But yes, a cache write is when you write to the cache. One of the problems with a cache write is that in order to be in a state where you have a cache write, it means you didn't already have the data you wanted in the cache.